How to make buttons clickable that are outside the 3d view? I cant press N-panel buttons
I have this addon Im trying to make to measure in blender. But Im having issues trying to make the UI interactable when the modal operator is running. PASS_THROUGH is working fine for the N-panel categories somehow, but not for anything else. I want to be able to toggle/press any button (including the menu) even it the modal operator is running.
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils
import blf

# Store the line coordinates and lengths globally
lines = []  # This will hold pairs of (start, end) points for each line
font_info = {"font_id": 0, "handler": None}
first_line_drawn = False  # Flag to indicate if at least one line has been drawn
lines_visible = True  # Control whether lines are visible or hidden
drawing_active = False  # Flag to track if the draw operator is active

# Shader and batch for drawing the lines
shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')

# Function to convert 2D mouse coordinates into 3D space (using a depth reference point)
def mouse_to_3d(context, event, depth_location):
    region = context.region
    region_3d = context.space_data.region_3d
    mouse_coord = (event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)
    return view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d(region, region_3d, mouse_coord, depth_location)

# Function to calculate the length of a line segment
def calculate_length(start, end):
    return (end - start).length

# Drawing the lines in the viewport
def draw():
    if lines_visible and lines:  # Only draw lines if they are visible
        for line in lines:
            batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {"pos": line})
            shader.bind()
            shader.uniform_float("color", (1, 1, 0, 1))  # Yellow color
            batch.draw(shader)

# Function to draw length text dynamically at the midpoint of each line
def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    """Draw the text at the midpoint of each line"""
    font_id = font_info["font_id"]

    if lines_visible:  # Only draw lengths if they are visible
        for line in lines:
            start, end = line
            length = calculate_length(start, end)  # Calculate length of the current line

            # Calculate the midpoint of the line
            midpoint = (start + end) / 2

            # Convert 3D midpoint to 2D screen space
            region = context.region
            region_3d = context.space_data.region_3d
            mid_2d = view3d_utils.location_3d_to_region_2d(region, region_3d, midpoint)

            # Draw the length at the midpoint if the midpoint is visible
            if mid_2d:
                blf.color(font_id, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  # RGBA for white color
                
                # Set the font size and position for the length text
                blf.position(font_id, mid_2d[0], mid_2d[1], 0)
                blf.size(font_id, 16)  # Adjust font size as necessary
                blf.draw(font_id, f"Length: {round(length, 2)}")

def init():
    """Initialize font for text drawing"""
    global font_info
    font_info["font_id"] = 0  # Use default Blender font

# Modal operator to handle mouse input and draw lines
class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Draw a yellow line with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_draw"
    bl_label = "Draw Yellow Line"
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_pos = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        global lines, first_line_drawn, drawing_active

        # Print a message to confirm the modal function is called
        print("Modal function called")

        # Check if the mouse is inside the VIEW_3D area
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            print("INSIDE VIEW_3D")  # Print when inside VIEW_3D
        else:
            print("OUTSIDE VIEW_3D")  # Print when outside VIEW_3D

        # Allow view panning with the middle mouse button
        if event.type == 'MIDDLEMOUSE':
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        # Allow zooming with mouse wheel or trackpad
        if event.type in {'WHEELUPMOUSE', 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE'}:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        # Check for mouse movement
        if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            if self.start_pos is not None:
                current_pos = mouse_to_3d(context, event, self.start_pos)
                # Update the last endpoint of the last drawn line
                lines[-1][1] = current_pos
                context.area.tag_redraw()  # Force redraw

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':  # Left mouse button click
            if event.value == 'PRESS':
                self.start_pos = mouse_to_3d(context, event, Vector((0, 0, 0)))
                # Start a new line with the start and a temporary endpoint
                lines.append([self.start_pos.copy(), self.start_pos.copy()])  # Append a new line
            elif event.value == 'RELEASE':
                if not first_line_drawn:
                    # Set flag to true after the first line is drawn
                    first_line_drawn = True
                    # Initialize font drawing routine to display the lengths
                    font_info["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                        draw_callback_px, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL'
                    )
                self.start_pos = None  # Reset the start position for the next line

        elif event.type == 'RIGHTMOUSE' or event.type == 'ESC':
            # Cancel the current line drawing but keep the lines
            self.start_pos = None  # Reset start position
            drawing_active = False  # Reset drawing state
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        elif event.type == 'RET':
            # Exit the line drawing mode without clearing the lines
            self.start_pos = None  # Reset start position
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            drawing_active = False  # Reset drawing state
            return {'FINISHED'}  # Exit drawing mode but keep lines

        # Allow interaction with other areas when not in VIEW_3D
        if event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE', 'RIGHTMOUSE', 'MOUSEMOVE'} and event.value == 'PRESS':
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        global lines, drawing_active

        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            init()  # Initialize font
            # Register both the line drawing and length drawing callbacks
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
            font_info["handler"] = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                draw_callback_px, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            drawing_active = True  # Set drawing state to active
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

# Panel in the N-panel (right side in the 3D Viewport)
class VIEW3D_PT_draw_line_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the N-panel (right-hand side)"""
    bl_label = "Draw Yellow Line"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_draw_line_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Tool"  # Appears under the "Tool" tab

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        # Button to initiate line drawing
        if drawing_active:
            # If drawing is active, change the button text
            draw_button = layout.operator("view3d.modal_draw", text="Drawing Line... (Click to Stop)")
        else:
            draw_button = layout.operator("view3d.modal_draw", text="Draw Yellow Line")

        # Button to toggle visibility of lines and lengths
        toggle_text = "Hide Lines & Lengths" if lines_visible else "Show Lines & Lengths"
        layout.operator("view3d.toggle_lines_visibility", text=toggle_text)
        
        # Draw a list of lines with delete buttons
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            row = layout.row()
            start, end = line
            row.label(text=f"Line {index + 1}: Start: {start}, End: {end}")
            # Pass the index through properties instead of as a keyword argument
            row.operator("view3d.delete_line", text="Delete").index = index  # Set the index property

# Operator to toggle visibility of lines and lengths
class ToggleLinesVisibilityOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Toggle the visibility of drawn lines and their lengths"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.toggle_lines_visibility"
    bl_label = "Toggle Lines Visibility"

    def execute(self, context):
        global lines_visible
        lines_visible = not lines_visible  # Toggle visibility state
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Operator to delete a line at a specified index
class DeleteLineOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Delete a line"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.delete_line"
    bl_label = "Delete Line"

    index: bpy.props.IntProperty()  # To identify which line to delete

    def execute(self, context):
        global lines
        # Remove the line at the specified index
        if 0 <= self.index < len(lines):
            lines.pop(self.index)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Registering the classes and adding the drawing callback
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_draw_line_panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToggleLinesVisibilityOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeleteLineOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_draw_line_panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToggleLinesVisibilityOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DeleteLineOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

